# Redirecting subfolder AND adding a querystring to the resulting url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I've moved a wordpress installation from a subfolder to the domain root.
I've redirected that subfolder successfuly via .htaccess but I'm completely unable to add a query string to it so I know when the client is coming from an old link while keeping any previous query string the request had.

The (only) code I have in the .htaccess file after the wordpress directives is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nbek.org/blog$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nbek.org/blog/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://nbek.org/$1?sublog=nox [R=301,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've also tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nbek.org/blog$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nbek.org/blog/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?sublog=nox [QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://nbek.org/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

With no success at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I've redirected that subfolder successfuly via .htaccess" - where is this code? The code you've added in your question won't redirect anything (except the last rule will result in a malformed redirect). Please edit your question to show your complete `.htaccess` file with the "successful" directives in place. The order of directives is important.

Comment: First code block redirects but doesn't add any query string. Second code block doesn't work at all. At the moment I have the first code block all by itself after the wordpress directives. There's nothing else in the .htaccess.

Comment: Your RewriteConds are bogus, the value `nbek.org/blog` is _not_ a host name. This doesn't need any conditions to begin with, matching on the path component of the URL can be done directly in the RewriteRule.

Comment: "First code block redirects but doesn't add any query string." - The first code block won't do anything because the _conditions_ will never match (as CBroe pointed out). So, either _something else_ is triggering the redirect or you are seeing a cached response/redirect (if you've been experimenting with 301 - permanent - redirects then these will be cached persistently by the browser, which naturally makes testing problematic.)

Comment: I won't pretend to know what I'm doing here but I can assure you the redirection is done fine. A bit slowly but fine. It's the query string what I'm not able to do. I've changed the `R=301` flag to `R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The (only) code I have in the .htaccess file **after the wordpress
> directives** is:
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On    
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/blog$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/blog/$
> RewriteRule (.*)$ https://example.com/$1?sublog=nox [R=301,QSA,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

As stated in comments, these directives cannot be doing anything since the *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) will never match. The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the value of the `Host` HTTP request header - this does not contain the URL-path. So, `example.com/blog` can *never* match.

You've also put these directives in the wrong place, they need to go *before* the WordPress code block, not "after". By placing this rule "after the Wordpress directives", unless `/blog` still exists as a physical directory then (again) these directive will never actually do anything since they will never even be processed (the WordPress code block catches the request and rewrites it to the front-controller at which point processing effectively stops). If `/blog` still exists as a physical directory then the preceding WordPress code block should ignore the request, allowing this rule to be processed.

> I can assure you the redirection is done fine. **A bit slowly** but fine.

This *might* suggest the redirect is actually being performed by WordPress itself, not `.htaccess`. However, this "should" be indicated in the HTTP response headers of the redirect response.

To redirect all requests from a `/blog` subdirectory to the root and include an additional URL parameter is just a one-liner.

For example, *before* the WordPress code block:

```
# Redirect "/blog/<anything>" to "/<anything>?sublog=nox"
RewriteRule ^blog(?:$|/(.*)) /$1?sublog=nox [QSA,R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

Or, ensure that it always redirects to HTTPS and the canonical hostname by including the scheme and hostname in the redirect (as you have done):

```
RewriteRule ^blog(?:$|/(.*)) https://example.com/$1?sublog=nox [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `/blog` to `/?sublog=nox` and `/blog/foo?bar=1` to `/foo?sublog=nox&bar=1` (preserving the initial query string).

The `RewriteRule` directive itself checks the URL-path in the first argument (ie. `^blog(?:$|/(.*))`). The additional "complexity" in the regex is that this will match both `/blog` (no trailing slash) and `/blog/<anything>` and still preserve the slash prefix in the *substitution* string without duplication.

The `QSA` flag appends the original query string (if any) from the initial request onto the end of the *substitution* string.

Additional notes:

- You do not need any additional *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) before the rule.
- You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive, since this should already occur later in the file, inside the WordPress code block.
- You do not need the `<IfModule>` wrapper around these directives. These directives are not *optional*.

---

#### Reference

The official Apache docs should be your go to reference for this (although the docs are rather concise and somewhat lacking examples in places):

- [Apache mod-rewrite Contents](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/)
- **[Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)**
- [Apache mod_rewrite Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

  - [`RewriteRule` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
  - [`RewriteCond` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: You are a wonder. Thanks a huge lot! One last thing. Do you have a link to somewhere I can actually learn to do this? All the documentation I've found is either too simplistic or too obscure.

Comment: @NoxNbek The Apache docs are my go to reference (although not to everyone's taste it would seem). The [mod_rewrite introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) is a good place to start. Note there are really two things here... regular expressions (regex) and the Apache directives. The Apache mod_rewrite directives happen to use regex - but this is not unique to Apache, it is the same regex engine (PCRE) as used by PHP etc. I've updated my answer with some reference links.

Comment: Many, many, many thanks. I doubt it but I hope I can return the favour someday :0)

Comment: @NoxNbek You're welcome. Once you reach 15 rep then you can also upvote answers you find helpful. ;o)